# How can I adapt my running technique to accommodate pushing a stroller?

Tags: running, exercise-technique, children

Since having children, I have taken up running because I can push them along. Sometimes I push one kid in a running stroller, other times I push two kids in a small-wheeled stroller that offers much more resistance. I have been reading and developing the [ChiRunning](http://www.chirunning.com) technique, which provides fairly detailed instructions about movement.

How can I adapt my running technique (ChiRunning specifically, or running technique in general) to accommodate pushing a stroller?

Some specific problems / questions that I am 'running' into:

1. One aspect of this method is to lean forward and use the constant state of falling for forward momentum. Does the backward resistance provided by the stroller mean that I should lean forward more/less/the same at a given speed?
2. What should I do with my arms and how close should my hands be to my body - there is the tendency for me to run into the stroller, but I can also keep it ahead of me with my elbows at 90 degrees and forearm perpendicular to the ground?
3. Is there any way in which I can benefit from using the stroller, for example by using the backward resistance to help me develop proper posture while leaning? 
   [image]

Comment: When you try pushing a stroller, while practicing ChiRunning, what problems do you run into? Do you hit the stroller or are you going too fast?

Comment: @ivo I will update my answer

Comment: seriously, this had me literally laughing out loud

Comment: @kjy112 why is that?

Comment: related: [How many extra calories do I burn when running with a jogging stroller?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5827/how-many-extra-calories-do-i-burn-when-running-with-a-jogging-stroller)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a link to [Chi Running with a stroller articles](http://www.chirunning.com/search/results/Y2hpIHJ1bm5pbmcgd2l0aCBzdHJvbGxlcg/).
They recommend using a Stroll-Smart attachment to free your arms allowing for better form and upper body movement.  If not using the attachment, here are some recommendations for a [newbie chi runner with a stroller](http://www.chiliving.com/forum/viewthread/1057/).

@Ivo - Summary of links:
Learning chi running with a stroller complicates the technique because the stroller interferes with your arm swing, limiting your upper body motion.  The stroller adds resistance; and with something in front of you, it tends to inhibit the forward lean making you stand more upright.

They recommend the stroll-smart adaptor, a bar that helps you push forward from your center rather than pushing forward with your arms.   It gives you the freedom and form that you are looking for with chi running.

If you are pushing a stroller without the stroll-smart adaptor,  avoid tensing the arms and shoulders, and resist the tendency to stand more upright - use your core.   You can switch off pushing arms.  Continue the forward lean of the technique, keeping your legs relaxed.

@David - One last point to your question about bending the elbows.  My study of Tai Chi addresses alignments and opening the joints to allow for the unrestricted flow of chi, so bending the elbows to 90 degrees may be too acute of an angle (in my understanding).   Also, you want a feeling of widening at the shoulders and underarms.   Go for that relaxed feeling of being propelled forward.

Comment: Care to summarize the information found when following those links?

Comment: @Ivo - I added a summary of links

Answer (score 2):

There is really nothing you need to change unless you have a problem.

Only difference is you will have one hand on the stroller making it go, so you will not have the back and forth motion on the one side. Just use the safety strap and jog away.

I have logged many miles with my single and double stroller, just remember that kids do get bored and hills become a real workout. :)