# How should jogging with a stroller change your stride?

Tags: running, running-form

I’ve recently purchased a double jogging stroller. I’m not a great runner to begin with—typically only lasting between 1 and 2 miles. I don’t know much about formal form concepts, but I was told once that my arms shouldn’t swing across my body because it leads to unnecessary core usage and ultimately you could tire faster. When running today, I noticed that my free arm was moving across my body and stopping myself from doing it took a great deal of effort on my part. Is this normal or should I continue to work on not swinging my “pumping” arm across my body when pushing a stroller?

Answer (score 2):

I am personally a fan of the [chi running](https://www.runnersworld.com/training/a20790888/find-your-chi-running/) technique. Here's a [question/answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/how-can-i-adapt-my-running-technique-to-accommodate-pushing-a-stroller) with how to adapt this technique to a stroller.

About the arms, this [article](https://www.healthline.com/health/exercise-fitness/proper-running-form#running-form) says to have a relaxed arm swing and avoid crossing arms in front of body.

I think it is normal and that running/jogging with a technique takes practice to master recommendations that improve the running/jogging overall.